# How to configure two different webapps to work with Apache on the same host/port?

Tags: python, apache, mod-rewrite, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I have apache server running two applications, written in php in python. The php one should be server on the root url, i.e. `localhost`. Python app is a restful app and should be under `localhost/api/`.

I heep confuguration of python app in separate file, where I have this line:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /api /home/user/my_app/deployment/deployment/wsgi.py
```

The problem is, now my python application is accessible under:

```
localhost/api/api/
```

and I want:

```
localhost/api
```

I can change `WSGIScriptAlias` to:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/my_app/deployment/deployment/wsgi.py
```

Because php app would not be accesible...
On the other hand I can't modify python app, which exposes urls, starting from `api`...

So I tried `mod_rewrite`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/api(.*) /api/api/$1
```

But this doesn't work either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From memory, use:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /api /home/user/my_app/deployment/deployment/wsgi.py/api
```

The addition of the '/api' to the end of the file path given as last argument causes mod_wsgi to adjust SCRIPT_NAME passed to the WSGI application and drops the '/api' from it and adds it to PATH_INFO instead. The application therefore would get the full URL to route on.

Answer (score 0):

When you have `WSGIScriptAlias /api /home/user/my_app/deployment/deployment/wsgi.py`, then the Python app should be accessible at `/api` instead `/api/api/`.

My guess is within your python app, in its configuration file you are setting the context root(I dont know the exact terminology) to serve from `/api` . If you change it `/` in the python app config, then it should fix it for you.

Comment: Let's assume that I can't left my "contex root" empty so it always have to be something.

Comment: Can you post your wsgi.py ?